# Turn array of jQuery elements into jQuery wrapped set of elements

Tags: jquery

Is there any elegant way of turning `[$(div), $(span), $(li)]` into `$(div, span, li)`?

What I need is a jQuery-wrapped set of elements instead of an array of jQuery elements.  I would like to do this in as few lines of code as possible, and with minimal (if any) looping.

**Edit:**  For those of you confused by this question, this code is copied and pasted from firebug using console.log on an array of elements that have **already been selected**.

Comment: jQuery needs to call the elements between quotes: `$("li")`

Comment: @jackJoe I think he's quoting firebug directly.

Comment: Do you really mean that you want to turn this: `[$(a), $(b), $(c)]` into the result of this: `$(a, b, c)`?  The The fact that all parameters are `li` is making this quite confusing.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant... I will edit my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[jQuery's `map()` function](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.map) is perfect for reshaping arrays and/or jQuery collections.

So, *given* an array set like so:

```
var arrayOfJQ_Objects = [$("div"), $("span"), $("li")];
```

**This one line of code is all you need ([See it in action at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gWVTc/)):**

```
$(arrayOfJQ_Objects).map (function () {return this.toArray(); } );
```

Resulting in this console display in Firebug:

```
jQuery(div, span, li)
```

Reference, also, [jQuery's `.toArray()` function](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=toArray).

Comment: the jsfiddle example is way over kill.. I'd down vote just for the 150 lines of code to demonstrate $.map()

Comment: Also works: `$(arrayOfJQ_Objects).map (function () {return this.get(0);});` or `$(arrayOfJQ_Objects).map (function () {return this.get();});`

Comment: "This one line of code is all you need" plus the 149 other lines of code. Why was this accepted as an answer, that wall of code is horrendous.

Comment: Just saying, that your answer is quite misleading, as in the body of the answer you mention it's 1 line of code, yet link to a fiddle with a gigantic wall of code with very little explanation, nor any context provided in the answer.

Answer (score 18):

If what you really mean is how to convert:

```
[$(a), $(b), $(c)]
```

into the result of:

```
$(a, b, c)
```

then you can use the add function to add each jQuery object to another jQuery object:

```
var x = $();  // empty jQuery object
$.each([$(a), $(b), $(c)], function(i, o) {x = x.add(o)});
```

At this point, x will contain a combined jQuery object that is the combination of the previous a, b and c jQuery objects in the array.

I couldn't find any way to do it without the `each()` loop.  The `add()` function accepts an array of DOM elements as an argument, but (at least according to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/add/)), not an array of jQuery objects.

---

Or, you could convert each jQuery object to a DOM element, which would likely be a little more efficient because it only makes one new jQuery object at the end:

```
$([$(".a"), $(".b"), $(".c")].map(function(o) { return o.get() }));
```

Comment: `add` returns a copy, so this is `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 8):

A bit more concise than the accepted answer, one can use the `$.fn.toArray` as the argument passed to `$.fn.map`:

```
var list = [$('<a>'), $('<b>'), $('<i>')];

$(list).map($.fn.toArray);
```

Or perhaps (this is really inferior, but only has one function call in your code):

```
$.fn.map.call(list, $.fn.toArray);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `add` method to copy the elements in a jQuery object to another. This will copy all elements from each of the jQuery objects in the array `source` into the jQuery object `items`:

```
// Create an empty jQuery object
var items = $([]);
// Add the elements from each jQuery object to it
$.each(source, function(){ items = items.add(this); });
```

(Prior to version 1.3.2 the `add` method doesn't support adding a jQuery object, so you would need to use `items.add(this.get());` instead.)

Comment: What is there reason not to do `var items = $()`? to create your empty jQuery object?

Comment: FYI, this solution only seems to work when I replace items.add(this); with items = items.add(this);  I'm guessing that .add() does not change the object it was called on.

Comment: @Scott Greenfield: That is correct. I have updated the code in the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Say you have an array of jQuery elements:

```
let elementList = [$("selector1"), $("selector2"), $("selector3"), ...];
```

You can simply use the jQuery function (`$()`) directly on the array which will return a jQuery set:

```
let jQuerySetOfElements = $(elementList);
```

Answer (score 2):

To add single element:

```
var $previousElements = $();
$previousElements.add($element);
```

to convert array to jQuery set of elements:

```
var myjQueryElementArray = [$element1, $element2, $elementN];
$(myjQueryElementArray ).map (function () {return this.toArray(); } );
```

to add array of elements to existing elements:

```
var $previousElements = $(),
     myjQueryElementArray = [$element1, $element2, $elementN];

$previousElements.add($(myjQueryElementArray).map (function () {return this.toArray(); } ));
```

Comment: to the point.. great answer.. thank you for not linking to 150 lines of js code in jsfiddle just to demonstrate .map()

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: I thought jQuery supported all `Array` methods, but nay, so here's a working version of my initial solution, albeit it's a bit odd since I am sticking to the same methods:

```
var set; // The array of jQuery objects, 
         // but make sure it's an Array.
var output = set.pop();
$.each(set, function (_, item) { 
    return [].push.call(output, [].pop.call(item));
});
```

Comment: Returns and removes the last item from an Array.

Comment: That would just create a new array that contains exactly the same as the old one did.

Answer (score 1):

If `Array.prototype.reduce()` is supported in your environment.

```
var jQueryCollection = [$("a"), $("div")]
                          .reduce(function (masterCollection, collection) {
                               return masterCollection.add(collection);
                          }, $());
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naMzE/).

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
var $temp = $();
$.each([$("li"), $("li"), $("li")], function(){
    $temp.push(this[0]);
})
```

$temp all your elements in one jQuery selector

But i am curious what brings you to this situation having an array of different jQuery elements. You know that you can select different elements using a comma? like `$("li, ul > li:eq(0), div")`

**edit** as Guffa pointed out, this only adds the first element of each section. `.add()` is a better choice then `.push()` here.

Comment: looks like we had the same idea.

Comment: That would only get the first element from each jQuery object, and there is no `push` method in jQuery.

Comment: or maybe the OP would like to target nested `li`? like `$("li li li")`?

Comment: @Guffa; True just tested it. But push is a native JS prototype no?

Comment: @meo: There is a `push` method in the Array object, and it seems that the jQuery inherits that somehow, but I can't find it documented.

Comment: At least for the version SO uses :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem long time ago. I have a huge form and I need to get every `input`. So, my idea was take each `input` as jQuery object and turn it into jQuery wrapped set of elements. How can I do that? Well this is the solution for your question.

1. First you need to create an empty array as a jQuery object like this: `let fields = $([]);`.
2. Now, use a string containing a selector expression to get the elements that you need in this example: `'form#details :input'` as jQuery Objects.
3. Then use `.each` method to extract the information that you need, and add the jQuery object to the jQuery set wrapper: `fields = fields.add(input);`

### How do you apply to this question?

If you have a list of elements `let elements = [$('#gw_id'), $('#erv_id'), $('#name')];` you can replace `$('form#details :input')` with `elements`;

Another, alternative is to use `.reduce` vanilla js. in this `let set = $(elements.reduce((acc, cur) => {return acc.concat(cur.get())}, []));` snippet we use the array of `elements` and apply `reduce` reduce has 4 parameters but we can use the first two that are `accumulator` as `acc` and `currentValue` as `cur` also we use the Arrow function (`=>`) to reduce the callback. In this callback we concatenate each current value in a new array. Finally, the return array is wrapped into a jQuery object `$()`. You can replace `elements` with `$('form#details :input')` also.

```js
let fields = $([]);
let elements = [$('#gw_id'), $('#erv_id'), $('#name')];

$(function() {
  console.log('List of fields: ');
  $('form#details :input').each((index, value) => {
    let input = $(value);
    let id = input.attr('id');
    let type = input.attr('type');

    fields = fields.add(input);
    if (id && type == 'text') {
      console.log('Input: ' + id + ' | Text: ' + type);
    }
  });
  fields.addClass('ui-state-error');


  let set = $(elements.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return acc.concat(cur.get())
  }, []));

  console.log('Set list: ');
  set.each((index, value) => {
    let input = $(value);
    let id = input.attr('id');
    let type = input.attr('type');
    console.log('Input: ' + id + ' | Text: ' + type);
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-state-error {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="details">
  <fieldset>
    <p>
      <label for="gw_id">GW Id</label>
      <input type="text" name="gw_id" id="gw_id" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="erv_id">ERV Id</label>
      <input type="text" name="erv_id" id="erv_id" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="description">Description</label>
      <input type="text" name="description" id="description" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="no" id="no" value="23" disabled readonly>
    <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
    <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$('li').each(function(){
    $(this).doSomething();
```

})

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to get accross with that answer.

Comment: I see what you mean, but how do you know the set of `li`s is the same as the set you'd be selecting?

Comment: I was asking about a group of elements that are already selected and stored in a variable, in the form of an array, not how to select a set of elements and do something.