# Create collection of objects, then add handler to all objects

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, is there a way to create an array of objects which it's then possible to add a handler to them all?

For example, I have a function that returns a jQuery object, and I want to call that function multiple times.  Each time the function returns an object and I want to add that object to the array.  Once all the objects are added, I want to add a handler to them all...

The following is a vast simplification of the desired result... the actual handler is much more complex, therefore I don't want to specifically add it each time

```
// I KNOW THIS DOESN'T WORK...
var allObj = [];
allObj.push(myFnc("#txt1"));
allObj.push(myFnc("#txt2"));
allObj.push(myFnc("#txt3"));
allObj.on("change", function() { alert("hello world"); });

// I also tried, this also failed
$(allObj).on("change", function() { alert("hello world"); });
```

I'm specifically interested to know if it's possible to create the object collection.

I'm aware that one solution to the above is as follows, but that is not my question...

```
function handlerFnc() { alert("hello world"); }
myFnc("#txt1").on("change", handlerFnc);
myFnc("#txt2").on("change", handlerFnc);
myFnc("#txt3").on("change", handlerFnc);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn array of jQuery elements into jQuery wrapped set of elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867184/turn-array-of-jquery-elements-into-jquery-wrapped-set-of-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/)

> Create a new jQuery object with elements added to the set of matched elements.

```js
var myFnc = function(inputId) {
  var id = inputId.replace('#', '');
  var div = $('<div >', {
    id: inputId.replace('#', ''),
    text: inputId
  })
  div.appendTo(document.body)
  return div;
}

var allObj = myFnc("#txt1"); //Create initial object using first function call
allObj = allObj.add(myFnc("#txt2"));
allObj = allObj.add(myFnc("#txt3"));
allObj.on("click", function() {
  alert("hello world: " + this.textContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Bingo - we have a winner.  Didn't occur to me to use the original object... and the important part is the assignment back to `allObj` (as I've just discovered). Thank you @Satpal  :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are two general ways to do this:

1. Work with it as with an array. Just utilize `Array.prototype.forEach` and apply handler to the every element:

   ```
   var allObj = [];

   allObj.push(myFnc("#txt1")); // I assume that myFnc returns jQuery object
   allObj.push(myFnc("#txt2"));
   allObj.push(myFnc("#txt3")); 

   allObj.forEach(function($elem) {
       $elem.on("change", function() { alert("hello world"); });
   });
   ```
2. Combine it to a jQuery object and work with it. One way to do this is described in @Satpal's answer. You may also turn your array of jQuery objects into jQuery array-like object, which is described in the following question:

   [Turn array of jQuery elements into jQuery wrapped set of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867184/turn-array-of-jquery-elements-into-jquery-wrapped-set-of-elements)

The second one looks more proper *for me*.

Comment: Thanks @Yeldar.  For the time being, Satpal's answer does what I need